# How to use SettingDefinitionGroup?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, settings, aspnetboilerplate

I use the free [multi-page template for ASP.NET Core](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) [v4.0.0](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/releases/tag/v4.0.0), which is based on the [ASP.NET Boilerplate](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate) [v3.8.1](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/releases/tag/v3.8.1).
The template already implements [AppSettingProvider](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Configuration/AppSettingProvider.cs), in which you can add the necessary settings for the application or user scope like [so](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/Configuration/AppSettingProvider.cs#L12) on. The problem is that I need to use a very large number of settings, which makes sense to group. To do this, the [*SettingDefinition*](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Configuration/SettingDefinition.cs) class has the [*SettingDefinitionGroup*](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Configuration/SettingDefinitionGroup.cs) [group property](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Configuration/SettingDefinition.cs#L43). But how to use it? The [official documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management#defining-settings) says that this serves just for use in the UI, but does not give an example of its use.

For example, there is such a structure of settings:

```cs
namespace ProjectName.Configuration {

    public static class AppSettingNames {

        public const string UiTheme = "App.UiTheme";

        public static class BaseData {
            public static class Company {
                public const string Name = "BaseData.Company.Name";
                // ...
                public static class PostAddress {
                    public const string Country = "BaseData.Company.PostAddress.Country";
                    // ...
                }
            }
            public static class UI {
                public static class Footer {
                    public const bool IsVisible = "BaseData.UI.Footer.IsVisible";
                    // ...
                }
                public static class Widget {
                    public static class Weather {
                        public const bool IsVisible = "BaseData.UI.Widget.IsVisible";
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How, in this case, to specify it in the `SettingProvider` and use setting groups in UI?

```cs
namespace ProjectName.Configuration {
    public class AppSettingProvider : SettingProvider {

        public override IEnumerable<SettingDefinition> GetSettingDefinitions(SettingDefinitionProviderContext context) {
            return new[]
            {
                new SettingDefinition(AppSettingNames.UiTheme, 
                    "red", 
                    scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, 
                    isVisibleToClients: true
                ),

                /* BaseData */
                new SettingDefinition(AppSettingNames.BaseData.Company.Name,
                    "default value",
                    displayName: "setting name",
                    description: "setting description",
                    scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant,
                    isVisibleToClients: true,
                    group: ?,
                    clientVisibilityProvider: new RequiresAuthenticationSettingClientVisibilityProvider()
                )
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently being used, so there is a little work to do to actually use it.

Configuration:

```
public class AppSettingProvider : SettingProvider
{
    // Hold groups
    public static List<SettingDefinitionGroup> Groups = new List<SettingDefinitionGroup>();

    public override IEnumerable<SettingDefinition> GetSettingDefinitions(SettingDefinitionProviderContext context)
    {
        // Create groups
        var group1 = new SettingDefinitionGroup("group1", new LocalizableString("group1_displayName", "sourceName"));
        var group2 = new SettingDefinitionGroup("group2", new LocalizableString("group2_displayName", "sourceName"));

        // Add groups
        Groups.Add(group1);
        Groups.Add(group2);

        // Configure hierarchy
        group1.AddChild(group2);

        return new[]
        {
            new SettingDefinition(AppSettingNames.UiTheme,
                "red",
                scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User,
                isVisibleToClients: true
            ),

            // Grouped
            new SettingDefinition("setting1_name",
                "setting1_defaultValue",
                group: group1
            ),
            new SettingDefinition("setting2_name",
                "setting2_defaultValue",
                group: group2
            )
        };
    }
}
```

UI model:

```
public class SettingGroup
{
    public List<SettingGroup> Children { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ISettingValue> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Helpers:

```
private async Task<SettingGroup> GetSettingGroup(string name)
{
    var groupList = AppSettingProvider.Groups.Where(g => g.Name == name).ToList();
    var settingDefinitions = _settingDefinitionManager.GetAllSettingDefinitions();
    var settings = await SettingManager.GetAllSettingValuesAsync();

    return GetSettingGroupsRecursively(groupList, settingDefinitions, settings).FirstOrDefault();
}

private List<SettingGroup> GetSettingGroupsRecursively(IReadOnlyList<SettingDefinitionGroup> groups, IReadOnlyList<SettingDefinition> settingDefinitions, IReadOnlyList<ISettingValue> settings)
{
    return groups
        .Select(group => new SettingGroup
        {
            Children = GetSettingGroupsRecursively(group.Children, settingDefinitions, settings),
            Name = group.Name,
            Settings = GetGroupSettings(group, settingDefinitions, settings)
        })
        .ToList();
}

private List<ISettingValue> GetGroupSettings(SettingDefinitionGroup group, IReadOnlyList<SettingDefinition> settingDefinitions, IReadOnlyList<ISettingValue> settings)
{
    return settingDefinitions
        .Where(sd => sd.Group?.Name == group?.Name)
        .Select(sd => settings.Where(s => s.Name == sd.Name).FirstOrDefault())
        .Where(s => s != null)
        .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
var group1SettingGroup = await GetSettingGroup("group1");
var group1Settings = group1SettingGroup.Settings;

// Check hierarchy
// var group2SettingGroup = group1SettingGroup.Children.First();
// var group2Settings = group2SettingGroup.Settings;
```

Comment: Many thanks! I hope that in the future the official documentation will be supplemented with this information.